# How difficult is the LuaJIT FFI?

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

I recently looked into Lua and it seems really nice. The only annoying thing is its lack of (standard) libraries. But with the JIT compiler comes along a nice FFI C interface.

Coming from a java background, i tried to avoid C as much as possible, so my question: has anyone some experience with LuaJIT, especially its FFI interface, and how difficult is it to set up a library for someone with little to no knowledge in C?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seemed really simple to me, and Mike Pall has some nice tutorials on it [here](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html), the lua mailing list also includes some good examples, so check out the archives as well

Answer (score 2):

> how difficult is it to set up a library for someone with little to no
>   knowledge in C?

Really easy. First, you need to declare the functions that you'd  like to use. Then, load the target library and assign it to a Lua variable. Use that variable to call the foreign functions.

Here's an example on using function `powf` from C's math library.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

-- Whatever you need to use, have to be declared first
ffi.cdef([[
   double powf(double x, double y); 
]])

-- Name of library to load, i.e: -lm (math)
local math = ffi.load("m")

-- Call powf
local n, m = 2.5, 3.5
print(math.powf(n, m))
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly the example does not work. ;) `powf` takes and returns `float`s not `double`s. A valid declaration should read: ```ffi.cdef([[
  float powf(float x, float y);
]])```

Comment: You're right. `powf` takes floats as arguments, not double. Thanks for pointing that out.